# run a command off a random shuf result in bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I'm new to programming in bash.  I'm trying to create a shell command that will randomly select from a list of commands and then run the specific command.

This is what I have:

```
#! /bin/bash
shuf -e command-1 command-2 command-3 command-4 -n 1

case $-n in

  command-1

cp -r /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistA/ac.mp3 /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistSongs/
  ;;

  command-2

cp -r /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistB/ac.mp3 /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistSongs/
  ;;

  command-3

cp -r /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistC/ac.mp3 /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistSongs/
  ;;

  command-4

cp -r /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistD/ac.mp3 /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistSongs/
  ;;

esac
```

Can anyone correct my code so that it can work? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What actually happens if you run that script? Your case statement is wrong as it's missing closing parenthesis after each case. In addition the variable probably should not be `$-n`. It doesn't look like you're currently saving the value of the shuffle command anywhere.

Comment: You should really be drawing just the file name and use a single `cp` command with that file name in a variable. And to draw the file, you can use the `sort` command, with its `-R` parameter (random sort): `file="$(ls */*.mp3 | sort -R | head -1)"` (ie, list MP3 files in subdirectories, shuffle, take first).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of that script is incorrect, but easy to fix:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=$(shuf -e command-1 command-2 command-3 command-4 -n 1)

target_dir=/home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistSongs

case $cmd in
command-1) cp /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistA/ac.mp3 "$target_dir/" ;;
command-2) cp /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistB/ac.mp3 "$target_dir/" ;;
command-3) cp /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistC/ac.mp3 "$target_dir/" ;;
command-4) cp /home/mark/Desktop/PlaylistD/ac.mp3 "$target_dir/" ;;
esac
```

While at it, I made some other improvements:

- Don't repeat yourself: extract the common target dir to a variable
- No need for the `-r` flag of `cp` to copy a single file

Comment: This is simply wow.  Thank you, thank you.  If you are ever in Toronto, let me know and your beer is on me!

Comment: @Mark beer in Toronto sounds nice, if I ever get there. If you could also mark the answer accepted that would be awesome.

Comment: Janos, sorry for the slow response.  I can't find where to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @Mark You see the up/down arrows for voting next to my answer? There's a check mark just under that

Comment: @mark See also https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers